# wpa_supplicant instantly drops EAP connection citing "reason=2"

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to connect to an EAP network by configuring `wpa_supplicant` using a configuration that works for another Raspberry Pi connected to the same network.

`wlan0` connects then immediately disconnects. It puzzles me that `reason=2` [seems to mean "Previous authentication no longer valid"](https://www.toomanyatoms.com/computer/disconnection_codes.html). How can it have become invalid in a few milliseconds? Or is there some other authentication hurdle I'm falling at?

Output from running via `sudo wpa_cli` and selecting `interface wlan0`.

```
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE 
<3>Trying to associate with SSID 'GovWifi'
<3>Associated with 86:15:44:a9:44:8f
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='started' parameter=''
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
<3>CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=26 -> NAK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='refuse proposed method' parameter='MSCHAPV2'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='accept proposed method' parameter='PEAP'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018' hash=8cc34e11c167045824ade61c4907a6440edb2c4398e99c112a859d661f8e2bc7
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018' cert=<snip>
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/CN=wifi.service.gov.uk' hash=5833c1b734359594ea18af9a5871b2e944b1070857e8eaa2a2be73d8ce5cddb7
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/CN=wifi.service.gov.uk' cert=<snip>
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:wifi.service.gov.uk
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-ALT depth=0 DNS:www.wifi.service.gov.uk
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='remote certificate verification' parameter='success'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STATUS status='completion' parameter='success'
<3>CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 86:15:44:a9:44:8f completed [id=0 id_str=]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=86:15:44:a9:44:8f reason=2 locally_generated=1
```

My `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=GB
ap_scan=1
network={
        ssid="GovWifi"
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        eap=PEAP
        identity="redacted"
        password="redacted"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

I have checked the system clock is correct.

Comment: Do you have a computer certificate or a user certificate?

Comment: I don't know. How do I find out?

Comment: Ask whoever delivered this certificate to you. Or check the certificate yourself: what identity does it prove: a user named John or a computer named Lenovo?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Nobody has delivered me a certificate. Please could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Raspbian buster. It seens to be a bug related with nl80211 driver, wpa_supplicant regarding the connection with WPA enterprise ([link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian/+bug/1834749)). So if you are going through the same problem as me then these are the two solutions:

1. Change the driver used from nl80211 to wext;
2. Downgrade your current wpa_supplicant version;

In my case, I just changed the driver and the problem was solved.